# CMake and pugixml

Tags: c++, cmake, pugixml

I am new to CMake and having trouble understanding how to use it.

I have a cross-platform c++ project. It builds using CMake and my `CMakeLists.txt` lives in a folder called `MyProject` along with the project. I checked out a pugixml git submodule and it now lives under `MyProject/pugixml`, with its sources being under `MyProject/pugixml/src`. It however has its own CMake file:  `MyProject/pugixml/CMakeLists.txt`.

How do I modify my `CMakeLists.txt` to also build and use pugixml? I tried something like

`include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${GENERATED_HEADER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} pugixml/src)`

and

`add_library(PugiXML deps/pugixml/src/pugiconfig.hpp deps/pugixml/src/pugixml.cpp deps/pugixml/src/pugixml.hpp)`

and

`add_subdirectory(pugixml)` in different combinations (these are examples I found on Github), but it doesn't work - I get `unresolved external symbol` errors, so I assume the cpp never got compiled.

Comment: `I get "unresolved external symbol" errors` - This means you need to **link** with a library. `add_subdirectory(pugixml)` just builds external library, but linking with it should be performed **explicitely** with [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: Also, consider using the more modern [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/target_include_directories.html) instead of the old `include_directories`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_subdirectory(pugixml)
target_link_libraries(MyProject PugiXML)
```

assuming `PugiXML` is the target name that is exposed by the CMake files in `/pugixml`.